# section replace with another section in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've two sections with different ids, first is **`id="nature"`** and second section is of **`id="birdy"`**. Both sections contains carousel in it but I kept one section hidden.

[image: Buttons and carousel]

I've applied this jquery code to replace sections on click. When I click on bird button, second section get replaced by first section successfully.

But when I click back on nature button nothing happens.
What I want is when the page is set to second section (**`id="birdy"`**), on click to the nature button it will show first section(**`id="nature"`**) again.

Please help me!

**HTML:**

```
<section id="nature">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="one" src="img/page.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="two" src="img/parallax.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic2
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="item">
                <img class="three" src="img/classic.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic3
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="birdy">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="one" src="Bimgs/file.jpeg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="two" src="Bimgs/file2.jpeg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic2
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="item">
                <img class="three" src="Bimgs/file3.jpeg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic3
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img class="three" src="Bimg/.jpeg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic4
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img class="three" src="img/classic.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic5
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img class="three" src="img/classic.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    pic6
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- button -->
<div class="container ntr-btn">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">NATURE</a>
</div>
<div class="container bird-btn">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Birds</a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#birdy {
  display: none;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bird-btn').click(function (e) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $('#birdy').css('display', 'initial');
        $('#nature').replaceWith('<section id="birdy"></section>');
    });
    $('.ntr-btn').click(function (e) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $('#birdy').css('display', 'none');
        $('#birdy').replaceWith('<section id="nature"></section>');

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: notice that when you click on '.ntr-btn', you are setting the #birdy section to display none and you are replacing that section with the nature section. So, now the nature section is in birdy but it's display is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simplifying your structure? Instead of manipulating the DOM by inserting and removing elements, you could just show and hide your sliders:

HTML - Add a generic class to your buttons:

```
<div class="container ntr-btn slide-selector">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">NATURE</a>
</div>
<div class="container bird-btn slide-selector">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Birds</a>
</div>
```

JQuery - Show and hide your sliders accordingly:

```
$('.slide-selector').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ntr-btn')){
        $('#nature').show();
        $('#birdy').hide();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('bird-btn')){
        $('#birdy').show();
        $('#nature').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: But my friend, bird section caraousel controls are not working @KyleMeenehan

Comment: @AishaSalman, my pleasure! When you say the bird section carousel controls aren't working, do you mean the left and right buttons? Can you put the code up on a Codepen or JSFiddle?

Comment: I've solved it now.
Anyways! thanks once again :) @kyleMeenehan

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would probably be (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bird-btn').click(function(e) {
    /* Act on the event */
    $('#birdy').css('display', 'initial');
    $('#nature').css('display', 'none';
  });
  $('.ntr-btn').click(function(e) {
    /* Act on the event */
    $('#birdy').css('display', 'none');
    $('#nature').css('display', 'initial');
  });
});
```

In other words just toggle the display of those sections depending on which button you click.

### Edit (changed "#birdy" => "#nature" in last line of code)

Comment: No my friend, this thing is not working for me.But thanks for trying this out for me :) @o4ohel

Comment: Sorry, see my edit ... (change #birdy to #nature  ...)